# Spark collect_list and limit resulting list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, limit

I have a dataframe of the following format:

```
name          merged
key1    (internalKey1, value1)
key1    (internalKey2, value2)
...
key2    (internalKey3, value3)
...
```

What I want to do is group the dataframe by the `name`, collect the list and **limit** the size of the list.

This is how i group by the `name` and collect the list:

```
val res = df.groupBy("name")
            .agg(collect_list(col("merged")).as("final"))
```

The resuling dataframe is something like:

```
 key1   [(internalKey1, value1), (internalKey2, value2),...] // Limit the size of this list 
 key2   [(internalKey3, value3),...]
```

What I want to do is limit the size of the produced lists for each key. I' ve tried multiple ways to do that but had no success. I've already seen some posts that suggest 3rd party solutions but I want to avoid that. Is there a way?

Comment: Can you give an example of what limiting the size of list means here? is it in terms of number of elements ? then on what basis are you limiting

Comment: I ve updated the question.

Comment: Could you use a udf to truncate lists that are too long?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a function that limits the size of the aggregated ArrayType column as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

case class KV(k: String, v: String)

val df = Seq(
  ("key1", KV("internalKey1", "value1")),
  ("key1", KV("internalKey2", "value2")),
  ("key2", KV("internalKey3", "value3")),
  ("key2", KV("internalKey4", "value4")),
  ("key2", KV("internalKey5", "value5"))
).toDF("name", "merged")

def limitSize(n: Int, arrCol: Column): Column =
  array( (0 until n).map( arrCol.getItem ): _* )

df.
  groupBy("name").agg( collect_list(col("merged")).as("final") ).
  select( $"name", limitSize(2, $"final").as("final2") ).
  show(false)
// +----+----------------------------------------------+
// |name|final2                                        |
// +----+----------------------------------------------+
// |key1|[[internalKey1,value1], [internalKey2,value2]]|
// |key2|[[internalKey3,value3], [internalKey4,value4]]|
// +----+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I have a folder on databricks titled leo c

Answer (score 6):

So while a UDF does what you need, if you're looking for a more performant way that is also memory sensitive, the way of doing this would be to write a UDAF. Unfortunately the UDAF API is actually not as extensible as the aggregate functions that ship with spark. However you can use their internal APIs to build on the internal functions to do what you need.

Here is an implementation for `collect_list_limit` that is mostly a copy past of Spark's internal `CollectList` AggregateFunction. I would just extend it but its a case class. Really all that's needed is to override update and merge methods to respect a passed in limit:

```
case class CollectListLimit(
    child: Expression,
    limitExp: Expression,
    mutableAggBufferOffset: Int = 0,
    inputAggBufferOffset: Int = 0) extends Collect[mutable.ArrayBuffer[Any]] {

  val limit = limitExp.eval( null ).asInstanceOf[Int]

  def this(child: Expression, limit: Expression) = this(child, limit, 0, 0)

  override def withNewMutableAggBufferOffset(newMutableAggBufferOffset: Int): ImperativeAggregate =
    copy(mutableAggBufferOffset = newMutableAggBufferOffset)

  override def withNewInputAggBufferOffset(newInputAggBufferOffset: Int): ImperativeAggregate =
    copy(inputAggBufferOffset = newInputAggBufferOffset)

  override def createAggregationBuffer(): mutable.ArrayBuffer[Any] = mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty

  override def update(buffer: mutable.ArrayBuffer[Any], input: InternalRow): mutable.ArrayBuffer[Any] = {
    if( buffer.size < limit ) super.update(buffer, input)
    else buffer
  }

  override def merge(buffer: mutable.ArrayBuffer[Any], other: mutable.ArrayBuffer[Any]): mutable.ArrayBuffer[Any] = {
    if( buffer.size >= limit ) buffer
    else if( other.size >= limit ) other
    else ( buffer ++= other ).take( limit )
  }

  override def prettyName: String = "collect_list_limit"
}
```

And to actually register it, we can do it through Spark's internal `FunctionRegistry` which takes in the name and the builder which is effectively a function that creates a `CollectListLimit` using the provided expressions:

```
val collectListBuilder = (args: Seq[Expression]) => CollectListLimit( args( 0 ), args( 1 ) )
FunctionRegistry.builtin.registerFunction( "collect_list_limit", collectListBuilder )
```

Edit:

Turns out adding it to the builtin only works if you haven't created the SparkContext yet as it makes an immutable clone on startup. If you have an existing context then this should work to add it with reflection:

```
val field = classOf[SessionCatalog].getFields.find( _.getName.endsWith( "functionRegistry" ) ).get
field.setAccessible( true )
val inUseRegistry = field.get( SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate.sessionState.catalog ).asInstanceOf[FunctionRegistry]
inUseRegistry.registerFunction( "collect_list_limit", collectListBuilder )
```

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate this is an old question but I was looking to do the same and now since 3.1.0 the *slice* function can help here:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("key1", ("internalKey1", "value1")),
  ("key1", ("internalKey2", "value2")),
  ("key1", ("internalKey3", "value1")),
  ("key1", ("internalKey4", "value1")),  
  ("key2", ("internalKey3", "value3")),
  ("key2", ("internalKey4", "value4")),
  ("key2", ("internalKey5", "value5"))
).toDF("name", "merged")

val result = df.groupBy("name").agg(slice(collect_list("merged"),1,2).as("limited_list"))

result.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----+------------------------------------------------+
|name|limited_list                                    |
+----+------------------------------------------------+
|key1|[{internalKey1, value1}, {internalKey2, value2}]|
|key2|[{internalKey3, value3}, {internalKey4, value4}]|
+----+------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UDF.

Here is a probable example without the necessity of schema and with a meaningful reduction:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

import scala.collection.mutable


object TestJob1 {

  def main (args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val sparkSession = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName(this.getClass.getName.replace("$", ""))
  .master("local")
  .getOrCreate()

val sc = sparkSession.sparkContext

import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._

val rawDf = Seq(
  ("key", 1L, "gargamel"),
  ("key", 4L, "pe_gadol"),
  ("key", 2L, "zaam"),
  ("key1", 5L, "naval")
).toDF("group", "quality", "other")

rawDf.show(false)
rawDf.printSchema

val rawSchema = rawDf.schema

val fUdf = udf(reduceByQuality, rawSchema)

val aggDf = rawDf
  .groupBy("group")
  .agg(
    count(struct("*")).as("num_reads"),
    max(col("quality")).as("quality"),
    collect_list(struct("*")).as("horizontal")
  )
  .withColumn("short", fUdf($"horizontal"))
  .drop("horizontal")


aggDf.printSchema

aggDf.show(false)
}

def reduceByQuality= (x: Any) => {

val d = x.asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[GenericRowWithSchema]]

val red = d.reduce((r1, r2) => {

  val quality1 = r1.getAs[Long]("quality")
  val quality2 = r2.getAs[Long]("quality")

  val r3 = quality1 match {
    case a if a >= quality2 =>
      r1
    case _ =>
      r2
  }

  r3
})

red
}
}
```

here is an example with data like yours

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

import scala.collection.mutable


object TestJob {

  def main (args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val sparkSession = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName(this.getClass.getName.replace("$", ""))
  .master("local")
  .getOrCreate()

val sc = sparkSession.sparkContext

import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._


val df1 = Seq(
  ("key1", ("internalKey1", "value1")),
  ("key1", ("internalKey2", "value2")),
  ("key2", ("internalKey3", "value3")),
  ("key2", ("internalKey4", "value4")),
  ("key2", ("internalKey5", "value5"))
)
  .toDF("name", "merged")

//    df1.printSchema
//
//    df1.show(false)

val res = df1
  .groupBy("name")
  .agg( collect_list(col("merged")).as("final") )

res.printSchema

res.show(false)

def f= (x: Any) => {

  val d = x.asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[GenericRowWithSchema]]

  val d1 = d.asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[GenericRowWithSchema]].head

  d1.toString
}

val fUdf = udf(f, StringType)

val d2 = res
  .withColumn("d", fUdf(col("final")))
  .drop("final")

d2.printSchema()

d2
  .show(false)
 }
 }
```